# Unrelated Table Query

Tags: sql, comparison, relationship

I have two tables one storing a students test scores (tblStudentScores) and another storing grade boundaries (tblBoundaries). See below

tblStudentScores

```
---------------------
| stuName| testScore |
---------------------
| carl   |    40     |
---------------------
| david  |    35     |
---------------------
```

tblBoundaries

```
---------------------
| grade  |   score   |
---------------------
|   A*   |    45     |
---------------------
|   A    |    40     |
---------------------
|   B    |    30     |
---------------------
```

I want a query that returns the students name and their grade for example:

```
---------------------
| stuName|   Grade   |
---------------------
| carl   |     A     |
---------------------
| david  |     B     |
---------------------
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

One simple method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select ss.*,
       (select b.grade
        from tblBoundaries b
        where ss.testscore >= b.score 
        order by b.score desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as grade
from tblStudentScores ss;
```

This query uses the ANSI standard `fetch first 1 row only`.  Different databases have different ways of expressing this . . . `limit`, `top 1`, or even other methods.

Comment: Perfect, thank you worked first time although I used LIMIT 1, as Fetch didn't seem to be liked? Result was the same.